# Creating protocols for plugin testing for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to create a protocol for testing plugin. What exactly should I do? Should I test it in different WP versions? And what else should I do? And what is a testing protocol? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've heard people talking about testing protocols, they typically just mean having a standard plan for testing your software. I'd highly recommend you look into Scrum and Test-Driven Development. If you're familiar with those workflows, you pretty much have your testing protocol established. (I'd also recommend reading The Agile Manifesto and The Pragmatic Programmer to help you learn about how to practically implement these development procedures).

Specifically looking at WordPress plugins, I'd recommend possibly having some unit tests (PHPUnit for PHP code, QUnit for Javascript). A set of manual tests is also a pretty good idea. As you develop, you should try to keep these tests up to date and make sure that they all pass before you release.

Also, I typically just say the minimum WP version required is whatever the latest WP release is to make testing easier on myself, then I can just run through my tests with each new release to make sure that nothing has been broken (however, it's rare that anything that breaks backwards compatibility is introduced into the WP baseline).

Comment: Thanks for briefly answer. This is the first time that I should test the plugin, which I didn't write. That's why I should need a plan, how to test it. I would test functionality on different version of WP. And also I will run the testing if some function from the plugin is deprecated. I will also try to use PHPUnit and QUnit and HTML validation. Do you think that it is enough for testing for large plugin?